# Creating a Filter Criteria in Journey Builder by comparing two Attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

When creating a Contact Filter Criteria in a Journey Builder Event, Decision Split Criteria or Goal, is it possible to define the criteria by comparing two Attributes in the Contact Model, instead of comparing an Attribute to a defined integer, string or date (that you manually enter into the input field)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the Contact Filter Criteria in a Journey Builder Contact Data Event, Decision Split Criteria or Goal, you can create an [attribute-to-attribute comparison](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/attribute_to_attribute_comparison/) relationship between a Contact Data Attribute and another Attribute by following the steps below:

1. Drag the first Attribute onto the Expression Builder panel
2. Drag another Attribute over the filter input field until a dotted cyan rectangle appears
3. Release the Attribute that you are dragging

Refer to screenshot below.

[image: attribute-to-attribute comparison]

Note that:

- You can only create relationships between Contact Data Attributes in your Contact model (not Event Data Attributes)
- The Attributes to compare cannot be nullable
- This feature is not available when creating a filter criteria for Salesforce Data or Campaign Events
- You can only compare only Attributes of the same data type (e.g. text Attribute to text Attribute)
- Encrypted fields are not supported

Answer (score 0):

I see that you can now compare contact data with journey data. This can be helpful in case a contact (contact key) appears multiple times in the source data extension (composite primary key) and you can split using attribute compare based on the second primary key (the first primary key being the contact key)